# How do I disable the ssl check in python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

I'm using urllib.request.urlretrieve to download a file to local.

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_string,file_name)
```

It throws error:

> ssl.CertificateError was unhandled by user code
>   Message: hostname 'foo.net' doesn't match either of 'a248.e.akamai.net', '*.akamaihd.net', '*.akamaihd-staging.net', '*.akamaized.net', '*.akamaized-staging.net'

If you copy the url into Chrome, it will show you a notification and you need to say something like "keep going to the url".

Comment: @JoranBeasley, [`urllib.request.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) does not accept `verify` keyword argument. Maybe you're confused with [`requests` library](https://python-requests.org).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use [`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) with [custom ssl context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl-contexts):

```
import ssl
import urllib.request

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

with urllib.request.urlopen(url_string, context=ctx) as u, \
        open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(u.read())
```

Alternatively, if you use [`requests` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve), it could be simpler:

```
import requests

with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    resp = requests.get(url_string, verify=False)
    f.write(resp.content)
```

Comment: I guess there are some typo for the first solution, This works fine :D 
with urllib.request.urlopen(url_string, context=ctx) as u:
  f = open(file_name, 'wb')
  f.write(u.read())
Not sure if we have requests library in Python3 tho

Comment: @BingGan, I fixed the typo. Thank you for your feedback. `requests` supports Python 3.x. `pip install requests` and benefit. :)

Comment: I am getting `Cannot set verify_mode to CERT_NONE when check_hostname is enabled.` even after setting `check_hostname=False`. Any idea?

Comment: ok, so we have to set the `check_hostname` before the `verify_mode`

Comment: `shutil.copyfileobj(u, f)` could be used instead of `f.write(u.read())`, to avoid loading the whole content into memory.

Answer (score 6):

Function `urllib.request.urlretrieve` doesn't accept any SSL options but `urllib.request.urlopen` does.

However instead creating a secure SSL context with `ssl.create_default_context()` and making it insecure you can create an insecure context with `ssl.SSLContext()`:

This:

```
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
```

is equivalent to:

```
ctx = ssl.SSLContext()
```

*(For Python < 3.5.3 use `ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)`)*

Which makes a nice one-liner:

```
import ssl
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://wrong.host.badssl.com/", context=ssl.SSLContext()) as url:
    print(url.read())
```

Comment: `ctx` (the first version) gives UNSUPPORTED PROTOCOL.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn that do you mean? How you get that error?

Comment: I got that error using your code, with the first definition of ctx, and a different url. So: 

with urllib.request.urlopen(my_url, context=ctx) as url:
    print(url.read())

I guess the website might not support a recent protocol, even if the certificate verification is off?

Comment: Yes, this trick is to disable specific checks of a certificate. Still protocol and ciphers have to match.