# Getting error while trying to download a PNG from url

Tags: python, selenium, ssl, web-scraping, automation

So I'm doing some web-scraping, and I'm trying to download an image from an URL.

Here's my code:

```
import urllib
from urllib import request

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'image.jpg')
```

I get 2 errors when I run this code:

> - ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:645)
> - urllib.error.URLError: urlopen error [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure
>     (_ssl.c:645)>

Tried to look up answers on Google, nothing helped.

Thanks

Comment: See this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770129/how-do-i-disable-the-ssl-check-in-python-3-x

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
import ssl
import urllib.request
url = 
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

with urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx) as u, \
        open('image.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(u.read())
```

**UPDATE**

If above is not working for you, you can use

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
url = 

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(webpage)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this code produce the exact same 2 errors.

Comment: @Michael I have added another option, check that one. i have tried this & its saving the image

Comment: @Michael it is kinda strange as its working on my system.

Comment: is openssl installed on your system. maybe that is the error. i found this on google