# Download .xls file

Tags: python, urllib

I've been trying to download a .xls file using `urllib` like this

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve as retrieve 
dls = "https://www.bvc.com.co/mercados/DescargaXlsServlet?archivo=acciones&fecha=2020-04-02&resultados=100&tipoMercado="
retrieve(dls,"Acciones.xls")
```

But I recieve a long error message starting with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\quiki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
```

and ending with:

```
urllib.error.URLError: urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)
```

I do not know if it has to do with the fact that the URL does not end with ".xls"

Comment: try install certifi: `python -m pip install certifi`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python)

Comment: Why don't you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error? There is also a chance, depending on how confidential the request is, to deactivate HTTPS. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770129/how-do-i-disable-the-ssl-check-in-python-3-x

Comment: If you can, use [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) for HTTP(S). It takes care of a lot of the messy details for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [urllib and "SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a ssl cert verification error. That means that the site's certificate is having some kind of problem.

Try this code, it disables the verification.

```
import requests

dls = "https://www.bvc.com.co/mercados/DescargaXlsServlet?archivo=acciones&  fecha=2020-04-02&resultados=100&tipoMercado="

with open("Acciones.xls","wb") as f:
    f.write(requests.get(dls,verify=False).content)
```

Hope it helps.