# urllib.request with socks5 proxy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib, socks

I want to use socks5 proxy in my code. How to do this?

My code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
url = "https://api.ipify.org/"
request = Request(url)
response = urlopen(request)

print(response.read())
```

In addition I can say that with http/https proxies
 I did:
`request.set_proxy(proxy_address, "http")`
before
`response = urlopen(url)`, but now it doesn't work.

**EDIT**
I found sth like that

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import socks
import socket

request = Request("https://api.ipify.org/")
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, IP_ADDR, PORT)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
response = urlopen(request)

print(response.read())
```

But it gives me 
`ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain`

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `urllib.request.urlopen` with `custom ssl context`: [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33770290/2481350)

```
import socks
import socket
import ssl
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

IP_ADDR = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 9050
url = "http://httpbin.org/ip"

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

request = Request(url)
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, IP_ADDR, PORT)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
response = urlopen(request, context=ctx)

print(response.read())
```